# Getting the right ID's on the right row?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm wanting to grab info from my SQL server, what I am trying to grab is the map name, best time on the map and the player who completed that time.

My current query is this:

```
SELECT maps.MapName, SEC_TO_TIME(TRUNCATE(Min(times.Time),3)) AS Time, times.PlayerID

FROM times

INNER JOIN maps ON times.MapID = maps.MapID

GROUP BY maps.MapID
```

I probably don't need some stuff in there but I'm not great at SQL.
Doing that query returns this:

```
MapName:       Time:            PlayerID:
map_name       00:00:09.440     42
map_name2      xx:xx:xx:xxx     15
map_name3      xx:xx:xx:xxx     65
```

And so on. The MapNames are correctly matched up with the right time. Whereas the PlayerID is not matched with the right time. In the times table, is the Time, the MapID and the PlayerID and in the maps table is the MapID and the corresponding map. I somehow managed to match up the MapName and the Time with the query I did (took me a bunch of fiddling).

How do I go about matching up the PlayerID also? After that I need to match the playerID with the User in the players table.

As I said I am new to SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your query works, you need to find the minimum time for each `map`.  You can do this using a `join`:

```
SELECT m.MapName, SEC_TO_TIME(TRUNCATE(t.Time,3)) AS Time, t.PlayerID, u.name
FROM times t INNER JOIN
     maps m
     ON t.MapID = m.MapID INNER JOIN
     (SELECT t.MapId, MIN(t.time) as time
      FROM times t
      GROUP BY t.MapId
     ) tmin
     ON tmin.MapId = t.MapId and tmin.time = t.time INNER JOIN
     Users u
     ON t.PlayerId = u.PlayerId
```

Comment: Works like a charm, but I'd like to replace the PlayerID with the actual player name(called User in the players table). How would this be achieved? I'm guessing I do something similar to what was done above, but I'm not sure where to start. EDIT: I worked it out, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Actually, one more thing, each row has a `style` number in the times table, I'd only like times that have a `style` = to 1. I'm not sure where/how to input something like this in the query.

Comment: @CBlank . . . Try adding a `where` clause to the outer query.

Comment: I've tried adding in multiple places but it is only returning syntax error, I'm not sure where to add it.

Comment: @CBlank . . . You should ask another question with layouts of your tables and the results that you really want.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
SELECT     maps.MapName, SEC_TO_TIME(TRUNCATE(Min(times.Time),3)) AS Time, times.PlayerID
FROM       times
INNER JOIN maps ON times.MapID = maps.MapID
WHERE      times.PlayerID = (SELECT PlayerID FROM times t WHERE t.Time = times.Time)
GROUP BY   maps.MapID
```